# What do a minotaur's rations consist of, and can a dragonborn eat them?

Tags: dnd-5e, equipment, races, unearthed-arcana, food-and-drink

I'm playing a game of 5e, and our dragonborn lost all of his rations from a magical key. He was given rations by our minotaur. What do those rations consist of? Would the dragonborn face any issues with eating these rations? I'm asking because this dragonborn is primarily a carnivore, and it seems to me that minotaurs might be herbivores, being bovine in appearance...

What do minotaurs eat, and would their rations be consumable by another race, specifically dragonborn?

Comment: I am not aware of any rules, but if you want a WorldBuilding perspective on this the question [What does the Minotaur eat?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/35499/what-does-the-minotaur-eat) on WorldBuilding.SE might be interesting for you.

Comment: Are you looking for a source specifically on Krynn/Dragonlance minotaur, since that's the variant of minotaur that the Unearthed Arcana playable version is based off of?

Comment: Traditionally, seven youths and seven maids of Athens...

Answer (score 45, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there are no official rules regarding the diet of either of these two creatures. As such, it would depend on the DM, as usual. However:

If you insist on using real world logic, keep in mind that while the head of the minotaur is indeed bovine (Thus its teeth are best suited for chewing plants, mostly grass) most of its lower body is still humanoid. This would include most of its digestive tract, meaning that its stomach can easily digest different types of meat.
In fact, the original minotaur in Greek mythology was exclusively a carnivore, as it feasted upon the human sacrifices that were sent into its maze.
Thus, an omnivoric minotaur is not out of the question- If you insist on realism, it would only have a bit of trouble ripping the meat with its teeth. But that's what cutlery is for these days.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66835/discussion-on-answer-by-arthaban-what-does-the-diet-of-a-minotaur-consist-of).

Answer (score 22):

I'm going to completely ignore the [dnd-5e](/questions/tagged/dnd-5e) tag, because this is a fluff question, not a crunch one.  The diet of the minotaur won't affect a bit of his game statistics.

While the question is about the Dragonlance brand of minotaur, let's indulge. The original analysis of the Greek minotaur monster is below.

The Krynn minotaurs are a different kind of minotaur than the original:

> Most of Krynn’s minotaurs are informally known as Blood Sea minotaurs, named for the treacherous ocean area in which they are commonly encountered.

The habitat of those minotaurs is the sea, so their diet will favor sea-food.  Onwards to their ecology:

> Minotaurs produce a variety of products, among the them smoked and canned fish, (...) Minotaurs eat a variety of food but they have a special taste for fish, mutton, and raw rains. They also enjoy strong ales and beers.

The shared rations is probably [smoked fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoked_fish), since it can stay edible for longer.  Canned fish would stay unspoiled for longer, and probably held as emergency rations (we called those *Iron rations* back in the old days).

#### Minotaur Lore...

For the "common minotaur monster", let us dig back into the AD&D 2e monster manual, and see the minotaur Ecology entry (page 252):

> **Ecology**
>   Minotaurs breed with human females to produce offspring, which are male minotaurs.
>   (...) They can live without food for years at a time, but are always hungry unless they are fed regularly.  They are meat-eaters, but their curse causes them to prefer a diet of human flesh. (...)

I'll skip past the "live without food" part, because characters should starve. But since minotaurs are human offspring, they can be considered omnivorous like humans, with a strong preference for flesh.

Of course civilized minotaurs won't eat human flesh... <sub>*very often or in public*</sub>

Comment: Can you elaborate on "characters should starve"? There is precedent in D&D for races which do not need to eat (or sleep or breathe).

Comment: @mattdm *should*, not *must*. you can add [flesh and blood] before [characters] if you want. *Flesh and blood characters should starve*... Of course if a berk is playing a rogue modron (planescape nostalgia), there is no need for food.

Comment: \*shrug\* There are races which can naturally cast spells or have abilities which work like spells. There are spells which provide sustenance. It's not so far-fetched that a magical flesh and blood character is sustained by a curse. But I'm looking for a _game mechanical_ reason for this recommendation. Is there a balance reason to declare that all characters should [be able to] starve?

Comment: While Krynn was not mentioned in the question, it is mentioned in the 5e minotaur source material.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast An improvement no doubt, but I find the up-front admission that the answer is not interested in actually interfacing with the question and its “indulgence” obnoxious and decidedly unhelpful. More than anyone but Mindwin should change in Mindwin’s answer, of course, but I maintain that as-is this is an unhelpful answer and my downvote remains.

Comment: @KRyan As does mine.  In my opinion, removing sentence number 1 would be a significant improvement to the answer, but as I have a real (personal) problem with any reply that uses the "crunch versus fluff" (which I view as a false dichotomy) I  feel that my objection to that second sentence is based on a subjective view of things, and may stray into " badwrongfun" attitudes as an objection to the answer.

Answer (score 9):

## Rations are rations are rations

Unless the minotaur bought "minotaur rations" because there was a sale on oats, rations are rations for PCs.  The dragonborn would also be able to consume rations bought by the elves and gnomes.  I would think the only difference between races would be for taste, but for the game mechanic, it's the same.  Unless you are also house ruling that some races need to purchase special foods, it's the same item on the price sheets.

> Rations (1 day); 5 sp; 2 lb. ([Basic Rules, p. 50](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf#page=50))

I know this is the same conclusion as some other answers, but they've based their answers on realism or biology.  This answer uses the game mechanics as it's basis (at least that's what I tried to do).

Answer (score 8):

While the mythical and monstrous minotaurs are human-eating carnivores, the 5e playable minotaur race is taken from the Krynn (Dragonlance) minotaurs, which don't have their diet mentioned [in their 5e source material from Unearthed Arcana](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/UA_Waterborne_v3.pdf) but are defined as "Diet: Omnivore" in their AD&D 2e Monstrous Compendium entry ([MC4 - Dragonlance Appendix](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/16963/MC4-Monstrous-Compendium-Dragonlance-Appendix-2e)). It goes on to note:

> Minotaurs eat a variety of food but they have a special taste for fish, mutton, and raw rains. They also enjoy strong ales and beers.

Seems to me like their taste in rations would be pretty compatible with that of a dragonborn.

No, I don't know what a "raw rain" is.  Grain?  Maybe an OCR issue, my books are in boxes right now but I'll check when they're back out.

Comment: Raw rains?  Is that a typo, or do they really like drinking water fresh from the clouds?  Strange item in the list.

Comment: @Brian Even minotaurs need a high fiber diet, and plenty of fresh water, to stay fit. ;)

Comment: Just checked 2e MM and they have Minotaur as "Carnivore" - the deeper reference to the Krynn setting was a nice find.

Comment: Did you ever get a chance to figure out what "raw rains" was about? :) (I'm looking at the PDF now, so I'm guessing it is an OCR issue since it also writes "but" as "bet" and has no punctuation between the sentences: "Minotaurs eat a variety of food **bet** they have a special taste for fish, mutton, and raw **rains they** also enjoy strong ales and beers.")