# Can carnivorous races survive on Goodberries?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, races

I'm playing a Tabaxi in my latest 5e campaign and so far I don't think we've touched our rations once, since we've always had a Druid with us to give us [Goodberries](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Goodberry#content) basically every day.

I just checked the Forgotten Realms Wiki entry on Tabaxi and discovered that [they are a carnivorous race](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Tabaxi); does this mean my character should have been getting sick from eating nothing but fruit all this time?

Comment: [Related] [What do a minotaur's rations consist of, and can a dragonborn eat them?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/108010)

Comment: [Related] [Can Goodberry be used on horses?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/113395)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**It's magic**

Goodberries are not really nutritious fruits, but the "delivery form" of a spell effect. As long as you are able to eat one (you are not made of inorganic material for example), you can benefit from it.

Comment: And biology too (sort of). Assuming you sort-of need to digest the berry that shoudn't be a problem either. Quite a few of the smaller felines, notably margays(1), eat fruits.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margay#Diet

Comment: The reason I thought it was worth making sure was because of an article I found that suggested that felines are obiligate carnivores, ( 'Carnivores that eat mostly meat are called obligate carnivores; they cannot properly digest vegetation.' - https://www.livescience.com/53466-carnivore.html ) though given the magical nature of Goodberry I imagine this wouldn't cause a problem, that or Tabaxi could be like the Margay and be able to eat fruits.

Comment: as for felines not eating vegetables, my cats are addicted to fruits, cabbages and similar weird stuff. and they do eat meat and cat food regularly.  hell, they even try to steal doritos and stuff like that, though they only succeed  1/20th

Comment: @Borgh Probably because they're not 100% carnivorous, look ferrets for example who are 100% carnivorous, giving them fruits or veggies can make them real sick

Comment: @CptEric At least you let them win when they roll a natural 20 :)

Comment: Now I know what to feed my pet Illithid. :)